# How to get coordinates (x,y) from a svg and put a text tag with a value

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm trying to do a web app on **React** to write guitar tabs, i'm doing the tabs with **SVG**. I think i know how to get the coords but the problem is i don't know how to put that **text** tag with a value, because it doesn't have a value attribute (i think so)

my function:

```
// Doesn't work
// Suppose that i want to add a 2
const clicked = (evt) =>{
    const { currentTarget: svg, pageX, pageY } = evt
    const coords = svg.getBoundingClientRect()  //<----- get the coords
    const text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','text') //<--- create the svg
    text.setAttribute('x', `$pageX - coords.x`) //<----- set the attributes X and Y with the mouse coords
    text.setAttribute('y', `$pagey - coords.y`)
    text.setAttribute('value', "2")             //<----- It doesn't work
    svg.appendChild(text)
  }
```

[image]

heres other function, but to put circles:

```
//IT WORKS
clicked(evt) {
        const {currentTarget: svg, pageX, pageY} = evt;
        const coords = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
        const circle = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
        circle.setAttribute('cx', `${pageX - coords.x}`);
        circle.setAttribute('cy', `${pageY - coords.y}`);
        circle.setAttribute('r', '5');
        svg.appendChild(circle);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text is not an attribute, it's content so you want to replace

```
text.setAttribute('value', "2")
```

with

```
text.appendChild(document.createTextNode("2"))
```